# Andorid: Get location after user is prompted to enable it

Tags: android, location

I want to get the current location of the device when the app starts. It works fine but if the location is deactivated it crashes. So i used some code to prompt the user to activate it but seems the program reaches the crash line before the location is actually activated. (before the user is prompted to activate it).

The enableLocation() method below is responsible for prompting the user and the getDeviceLocation() for getting the location. I've tried placing the getDeviceLocation() in the in the onstart method and the enableLocation() in the oncreate but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

In the uber app for example  the R.id.contrainer frame layout seems to be replaced with a dummy fragment (instead of the SupportMapFragment) IF location is disabled. And by clicking a button the user is prompted to enable it. Then the SupportMapFragment replaces the dummy fragment (from what i've understood). But all this seems too much. Is it the only way?

```
oncreate() {
....
    SupportMapFragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
..... 
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Prompt the user for permission.
    getLocationPermission();

    // Prompt the user to enable location if it is disabled
    // by using Task<LocationSettingsResponse>
    // and LocationSettingsRequest.Builder
    enableLocation();

    // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
    updateLocationUI();

    // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
    // uses Task.getResult which returns null because location
    // is yet to be activated despite chosing to do so above
    getDeviceLocation();
}

// inside getDeviceLocation();
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult(); // RETURNS NULL HERE
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                LastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> private void getCurrentLocation() {

```
    gps = new GPSTracker(context, getActivity());
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
         return;
        }
        currentLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = gps.getLongitude();
    } else {
        showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```